# Split in SQL Query Problem

Tags: sql, database

I have a string suppose "ABCDEF" in SQL.

I want to show in the following table format:-

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

How can I do that without using CURSOR etc.

Comment: **What** database and version?? String manipulation is quite dependant on the actual vendor - not much in terms of standardization for that topic....

Comment: Also, can you explain why you want to do that. I'll bet some of us have a good way you could avoid the need to do that at all if we understood the core problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
with rec(recText, letterno) AS
(
    Select LEFT('ABCDEF',1),
            1
    Union all
    Select Left(RIGHT('ABCDEF',len('ABCDEF') - rec.letterno),1),
            letterno +1
    from rec
    where   rec.letterno < len('ABCDEF')
)
select top 1 STUFF( (   
SELECT ' '+recText FROM rec   FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '')  FROM rec
```

t-sql 2008 solution don't know if this caters for your question

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server, you can use

- SUBSTRING function to get one letter from a string
- master..spt_values to get a predefined number sequence (up to length 2047)

From a variable

```
declare @str varchar(100) set @str = 'ABCDEF'
select SUBSTRING(@str, number, 1)
from master..spt_values
where type='P' and number between 1 and LEN(@str)
order by number
```

And if you are splitting from a column in table

```
create table strtest (id int, str varchar(100))
insert strtest select 1, 'abcdef'
insert strtest select 2, 'qwertyui'

select t.str, v.number, SUBSTRING(t.str, v.number, 1)
from strtest t
inner join master..spt_values v
  on v.type='P' and v.number between 1 and LEN(t.str)
order by t.id, v.number
```

If you are using any other DBMS, you can do something similar, but create the number table if there isn't one ready.

Comment: @Vipin - Great to hear that. The norm on this site is to tick the answer as accepted if it solves the problem.